# Dockerized Jenkins on GCP Kubernetes gives "No valid crumb was included in the request"

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I've tried to run the latest Jenkins (2.19.3) on Google Cloud Platform, by directly deploying the Jenkins Docker image. The process starts fine, but as soon as I try to use some form (e.g. to create a user) I get the  "No valid crumb was included in the request" error.

The command used to deploy the image is:

`kubectl run jenkins-node --image=eu.gcr.io/tidalwave-services/jenkins --port=8080`

The cluster has been created by just following the Google tutorial. A dockerised version of Nexus 3 works fine.

"No valid crumb..." appeared a number of times in the past in various bugs, but they have been fixed AFAIK. The Docker image runs fine in a local Docker installation. At Jenkins' they immediately closed the issue I filed, as they say that the problem is with the deployment facility.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39885

I suppose that the problem is actually in the way the port 8080 is exposed by Kubernetes on the public IP, but at this point I have no clue, because I don't know about the inner workings of Kubernetes.

Comment: Although this might not be the version you are looking for, I would suggest following the approach proposed on this [article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-container-engine-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the steps for getting Jenkins properly configured and up and running on Kubernetes can be found in the Google Cloud Platform articles [Configuring Jenkins for Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/configuring-jenkins-container-engine) and [Setting up Jenkins on Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-container-engine-tutorial).